# Spinner-список под ToolBar

Tags: android, android-spinner

Как именно c использованием `Spinner`-а реализовать подобное выпадающее меню?(чтобы итемы не задевали `Toolbar`. 
Просмотрел много примеров, везде выпадающий список задевает `Toolbar`.

Или же лучше реализовывать по-другому?

**Меню в раскрытом состоянии:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Меню в скрытом состоянии:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам себе:

1. Необходимо создать адаптер для `Spinner`, и унаследовать его от `BaseAdapter` - таким образом мы можем сами сверстать выпадающий и фиксированный `layout` .
2. Сам отступ выпадающего списка от Toolbar можно задать вот так: `android:dropDownVerticalOffset="12.0dip"` (в `Spinner`).